# C++ finding the shortest path, reducing time complexity, dijkstra v Floyd Warshall Algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, graphs, shortest-path

I have an algorithm that I am performing on a graph and I am looking to do an analysis of how to speed it up and would appreciate any comments.

The algorithm iterates over every edge in the graph.

For each edge it (1) finds the shortest path from the input node of the graph to the source node of the edge **(Task 1)**.

It then (2) finds the shortest path from the sink node of the edge to output node of the graph **(Task 2)**.

Doing this process for every edge is what is causing it to be slow.

I am currently using dijkstra's algorithm implemented with using priority queues in C++ to find the shorest paths. According to [this website](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dijkstras-shortest-path-algorithm-using-priority_queue-stl/) the complexity of this is O(ELogV)).

There are a couple of ways that I think I could improve this.

1. There is a lot of redundant calculation going on. Once I've found the shortest path from a node to the output for example **(Task 2)**, I know the shortest path for every node along the path from the node where I started. I am wondering what is an efficient way to implement this, which C++ STL containers to use? Is there anyway to estimate the decrease in complexity?
2. A different approach would be to use [Floyd Warshall Algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/floyd-warshall-algorithm-dp-16/) which finds the shortest distances between every pair of vertices in a DAG. The complexity of this is O(V^3). Would it then be quicker to look this information up when computing the shortest paths? How could I quantify how much faster this approach is.

Comment: Dijkstra's algorithm finds the shortest distance from the input node to *each* node in the graph. Applying it to the reverse graph, it will find the shortest distance from *each* node in the graph to the output node. So you just need two applications of the algorithm. That would be quicker than Floyd-Warshall.

Comment: Questions specific to C++ are off-topic here.

Comment: I think the question applies as long as it refers to specific questions of graphs ... Those are my two cents ... I think it is rather unlikely that people in the c++ chapter are also knowledgeable on graph Search